# Canvas Binding Keys Not Defined

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a bit of a calculator app, and tkinter is binding keys that I didn't define yet. Here are the keys that I've binded so far:

```
canvas.bind_all('<Key-0>', self.zero)
canvas.bind_all('<Key-1>', self.one)
canvas.bind_all('<Key-2>', self.two)
canvas.bind_all('<Key-3>', self.three)
canvas.bind_all('<Key-4>', self.four)
canvas.bind_all('<Key-5>', self.five)
canvas.bind_all('<Key-6>', self.six)
canvas.bind_all('<Key-7>', self.seven)
canvas.bind_all('<Key-8>', self.eight)
canvas.bind_all('<Key-9>', self.nine)
canvas.bind_all('<BackSpace>', self.delete)
canvas.bind_all('<Key-+>', self.add)
canvas.bind_all('<Key-->', self.subtract)
canvas.bind_all('<Key-*>', self.multiply)
canvas.bind_all('<Key-/>', self.divide)
canvas.bind_all('<Return>', self.enter)
```

I've tried to see which keys do what, and here's what I got.

When I press shift, it does the `self.delete` function, and for every other key I press, it does the `self.add`, `self.subtract`, `self.multiply`, and `self.divide` functions.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Edit:

If I press 6, it will do the `self.six` function.
If I press BackSpace, it will do the `self.delete` function.
If I press Shift-=(or +), it will do `self.delete` and then `self.add`.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what it is you're asking. if you press, for example, `6`, what happens?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The little bit of code you posted isn't enough for us to duplicate the problem. What would be best is if you could just show two or three bindings that still reproduce the fact that pressing shift alone calls `self.delete`. Tkinter's binding mechanism is very robust, well tested, and deterministic.

Comment: ok done that I suppose

Comment: Try replacing `<Key-0>` to `0`, `<Key-1>` to `1`, etc.

Comment: *"When I press `shift`, it does the `self.delete`"*: **That's not possible**, `shift` is a **dead** key and will work only together with another key.

Comment: thats sort of what happens